# visudo problem on Debian

Tags: linux, debian, sudo

Recently I migrated from Ubuntu to Debian, first thing i wanted to do was to give myself sudo permissions and lock the roir account. By default sudo group don't have permissions to do this on debian, so i wanted to edit sudoers file by typing visudo. But i keep getting this error:
Error opening terminal: vanilla
How can i solve this, Thanks in advance...

Comment: This question is probably better suited for http://unix.stackoverflow.com

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
export TERM=vt102
```

before running `visudo`. This might help:

- http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/slackware-14/error-opening-terminal-xterm-terminal-type-xterm-unknown-718073/

Comment: No prob - note that there is probably something wrong in the setup if `visudo` is searching for `vanilla` terminal instead of something else, you should probably take a look at that. It might also depend on the way you are accessing it. E.g. if you access it from a Cygwin ssh, you will have TERM=cygwin instead, which is normal, but generally you should have TERM=xterm if within GUI or something more standard.